# Why is Stack Overflow showing `owner` class after logout?

Tags: discussion

I just found a thing inside Stack Overflow. I added a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40100906/code-will-be-execute-or-stop-if-validation-fail-in-laravel) then I removed my browser cookie and cache everything, so automatically I signout. But Stack Overflow still shows the `owner` class which indicating the owner name in the comment. I added a screen shot of my question (after logout) for reference.

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "owner" class is there because the comments are those of the question poster.

This has nothing to do with whether you are logged in or not.

---

You posted the question, and any comment you make on the question will have this highlight. Look at any other question by any other person who has also commented on their question—such comments will be highlighted.

Comment: Ohh OK understood now, Great Functionality...